# SVG no longer displayed in Bootstrap tooltips

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, tooltip

With the previous versions of Bootstrap, inline SVG were displayed in tooltips. With the current version, inline SVG are not displayed. I made a JSFiddle to show the problem :

[https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/3c9tnz6h/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/3c9tnz6h/7/)

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-secondary" 
  data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="bottom" 
  data-html="true" 
  title='SVG not displayed: <svg fill="red" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path serif:id="shape 22" d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12z"/></svg>'>
  SVG is not displayed here
</button>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'd suggest raising an issue in [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29858) but you've already done that so there's not much we can do here.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if it is an issue or something I did wrong.